# FB.login not calling callback if cancel is selected

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm trying to get the users permission if they haven't granted the publish_stream permission.

I have this function:

```
        function AskPermission()
        {
            ResizeUnity(0);

            FB.login(function(response)
            {
                alert("Hit");
                if (response.authResponse) 
                {
                    alert('Granted!');
                    GetUnity().SendMessage("POST", "POST", "Granted");
                }
                else 
                {
                    alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                    GetUnity().SendMessage("POST", "POST", "");
                }

                ResizeUnity(1);
            }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});  
        }
```

When it's called a small window pops up asking .... would like to access your public profile and friends list. There's 2 buttons Okay and cancel. When Okay is pressed it goes on to another screen asking .... would like to post to your friends on your behalf. Again 2 button, Okay and Skip.

When I press the first skip denying all permissions it doesn't return anything. the alert("Hit"); is not called.

When I do press Okay on the first prompt it goes on to the second popup and asks about the posting on behalf. I press Okay, the alert 'Granted' is called.

When I press skip the alert 'Granted' is also called even though I hit skip.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem from Unity on an Android - the callback is not called, if the user clicks the little "x" cancel button.

Answer (score 3):

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {    
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
       // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
       // app, and response.authResponse supplies
       // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
       // request, and the time the access token 
       // and signed request each expire
      var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
      var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized'){
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app
    } else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
});
```

Use this Facebook function to check whether user grant permissions or not.

You can recall same function if user not permitted your app. For more assistance in code, I can help you. :)

For more information see :[Fb.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is happening because you are trying to open Facebook login in a popup but it opens in the same window where you called fb.login. When you click Cancel, Facebook tries to close the window, but as it wasn't opened by facebook the window won't close. It never tries to follow the callback url.

Try using in the config {display: "touch"} or {display: "page"} like this:

```
    function AskPermission()
    {ResizeUnity(0);

        FB.login(function(response)
        {
            alert("Hit");
            if (response.authResponse) 
            {
                alert('Granted!');
                GetUnity().SendMessage("POST", "POST", "Granted");
            }
            else 
            {
                alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                GetUnity().SendMessage("POST", "POST", "");
            }

            ResizeUnity(1);
        }, {scope: 'publish_stream', display: 'page'});  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why not to ask for all the permissions to need in one screen itself. Howevern, keep in mind that as per facebook documentation, ask few permissions to begin with and then keep increasing the permissions request on the go.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions

Try this code

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
     console.log('Access Token = '+ access_token);
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
     console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: ''});
```

Hope that helps